# Nifi getTCP processor doesnt get any TCP data

Tags: apache-nifi

I am struggling to figure out which Nifi processor to use for this usecase. I have a remote TCP host:port which generates some TCP messages and I need to receive this data in Nifi and write to a file. I tried getTCP processor but it just keeps increasing tasks/time without getting data stream. I tried a small python script below to get some data on the Nifi server from the remote host:

```
import socket
host = 'x.x.x.x'              # remote TCP host
port = 9999                   # port used by the remote TCP host
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
data = s.recv(4096)
print('Received1:', str(data))
data = s.recv(4096)
print('Received2:', str(data))
s.close()

Below is the output data received from TCP server by the script:
Received1: b'\x02|12345|xyz|18.161|-56.195|10/31/2023 12:29:26 PM|0|UPS|\x03|0|0'
Received2: b'\x02|67890|xyz|18.709|-57.531|10/31/2023 12:29:27 PM|0|UPS|\x03|0|0'
```

There doesn't appear to be any CR-LF byte between each record received and the getTCP processor seems to be unable to figure out the data and so zero flowfiles are produced and zero bytes received. Any thought how to get the TCP data??

Comment: just a guess - maybe delimiter is zero-byte? another guess - i see every message starts with `\x02` - maybe `2` is the message delimiter?

Comment: read documentation of the protocol for the device that you are reading from. there should be information where the tcp message ends

Comment: Thanks, I did try 2 in GetTCP "End of message delimiter byte" but still didnt get any data. Since each s.recv(4096) in above script is returning one record per call, I was able to read each TCP record by running above python code in Executeprocess and sending the data to a Putfile processor which shows each record as a separate line with CRLF.

Comment: GetTCP has 2 outputs. maybe you getting them through `Partial` relationship?

Comment: I clicked both Partial and Success so should get both. Actually I do see data now from GetTCP but it is not separating into records in flowfile but coming as a single large string of bytes combined together. Also found out that control character for STX \x02 Start of text  and ETX \x03 End of text but someone added two fields after \x03 somehow.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX

Comment: so, `End of message delimiter byte = 3` should work for you.

Comment: It should work with End of message delimiter byte = 3 but there may be a bug in GetTCP as it doesn't split the records at \x03 delimiter but combines all the records into a single flow file and sends to next Putfile processor.